When using rows.Values() in Go's pgx, How can I know if the value was NULL without resorting to use rows.Scan()?
I want to iterate over the values in a row with rows.Values() and that works but there is no clear way how can I check if each value has NULL (valid/invalid):
rows, err := conn.Query(context.Background(), query)
// check err
fields := rows.FieldDescriptions()
for rows.Next() {
  for i, v := range rows.Values() {
    fmt.Println("field:", field[i], "value:", v, "is_null:", v == nil) // v is never nil
    if b,ok := v.(pgtype.Bool); ok { // the query returns some rows where one of the boolean columns is NULL
      fmt.Println("field:", field[i], "value:", b.Bool, "is_null:", !v.Valid) // v is never a pgtype.Bool the underlying concrete type is just bool
    }
  }
}

I know I could use rows.Scan() instead but then I won't be able to iterate over all the values in the same way. I just want to dynamically print all columns, values, and null status without having to specify each column individually.

I'm just guessing, but most likely v is going to contain the nil of a pointer type that matches the destination field and/or source column. And since an interface with a typed nil value is itself NOT nil, you'll have to use reflection or type assertion to check for the "nested" nil. E.g. try something like: reflect.ValueOf(v).IsNil().

https://go.dev/play/p/sBv1oTZeTgS

Btw. if the target field's type is not-nilable, e.g. bool v. *bool, then it's also possible to gracefully handle NULLs by simply ignoring them and leaving the target field untouched with its "zero" value. This would mean, if I'm not mistaken, that the information about NULL will be discarded, leaving you to have to look for a different solution. All that said, I'm not familiar enough with pgx to know whether it gracefully ignores NULLs or not.

No, v is just a bool, like reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Bool. In this case I really need to know if is was NULL or not, I do want map NULL->"unknown", true->"success", false->"failure", I do not want to make (NULL or false) -> "failure"

The values returned by rows.Values() should be just nil values for the NULL in the database
For example the following table has rows with null, true and false for col1
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 as select * from (values 
(null::bool, 'entry1'::varchar), 
(false::bool, 'entry2'::varchar),
(true::bool, 'entry3'::varchar)
)
as t (col1, col2);;
ALTER TABLE table1 OWNER TO myuser;
select * from table1;

The following go code using pgx, will iterate over all rows printint the rows.Values():
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close(context.Background())

    rows, err := conn.Query(context.Background(), "select * from table1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Connect failed: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    fmt.Println("Query returned")

    i := 0
    for rows.Next() {
        i = i + 1
        fmt.Println("row", i)
        values, err := rows.Values()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Values failed: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        for i, v := range values {
            fmt.Println("value", i, v) // v can be nil!!
        }
    }

    if rows.Err() != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Rows iteration error: %v\n", rows.Err())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println("Total rows", i)

}


will return
go run main.go
Query returned
row 1
value 0 <nil>
value 1 entry1
row 2
value 0 false
value 1 entry2
row 3
value 0 true
value 1 entry3
Total rows 3

which demonstrates the first value for row 1 is <nil>. If you are not getting nil values for NULLs it must be for another reason.
